# jQuery dynamic text (or data) on click change problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-data

I have an html file as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
.style1 {
    background-color: #c3d9ff;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
}
.style2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style3 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style4 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
background-color: ;
}
.action_button {
font-weight:bold;
float:right;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $(".action_button").click(function()
    {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function()
        {
            if(id % 2)
            {
                parent.fadeOut('fast', function() {$(this).fadeOut();$(this).fadeIn();});
            }
            else
            {
                parent.fadeOut('fast', function()   {$(this).fadeOut();$(this).fadeIn();});
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    }
);});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.action_button').click(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Inactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate');
        var $col5 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.clickme2');
        $col5.text( $col5.text() == 'Inactive' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 90%" align="center" class="style1">
<tr>
        <td colspan="7" class="style2">MANAGER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col1</td>
  <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col2</td>
  <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col3</td>
  <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col4</td>
  <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col5</td>
  <td class="style3" style="width: 200px">Col6</td>
  <td class="style3" style="">Action</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<td id="main" class="main">
 <td class="update">
<table style="width: 90%" align="center" class="style1">
    <tr>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA1</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA2</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA3</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA4</td>
        <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataA6</td>
   <td>
            <button href="#" id="DataA1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
            Activate</button>
            </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB1</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB2</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB3</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB4</td>
        <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataB6</td>
   <td>
            <button href="#" id="DataA1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
            Activate</button>
            </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC1</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC2</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC3</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC4</td>
        <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Active</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataC6</td>
   <td>
            <button href="#" id="DataA1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
            Inactivate</button>
            </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD1</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD2</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD3</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD4</td>
        <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Active</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataD6</td>
   <td>
            <button href="#" id="DataA1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
            Inactivate</button>
            </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE1</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE2</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE3</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE4</td>
        <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
  <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataE6</td>
   <td>
            <button href="#" id="DataA1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
            Activate</button>
            </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</td>
</td>
</body>
</html>
```

The page contains a table with a button at the end of each row. The button has function to change text (that is, when user click button, the text on the button and col5 swaps as pre-defined). Clicking "Activate" button changes the button text to "Inactivate" and col5 text to "Active". Also, clicking "Inactivate" button changes the button text to "Activate" and col5 text to "Inactive". But "Inactivate" button is not doing the stuff well.
The php file action.php is not relevant here because it is not printing anything.

Thanks in advance

blasteralfred :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the issue with the inactivate button use a trim with the text() function. i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.action_button').click(function() {
                 $(this).text($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Inactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate');
        var $col5 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.clickme2');
        $col5.text( $.trim($col5.text()) == 'Inactive' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also please note the correction mentioned by Jacob regarding reference to this.

EDIT: Updated to use $.trim instead of String.trim

Comment: You should *not* use `.trim()`, but `$.trim()` instead, like this: `$.trim($(this).text())`, IE<9 does not have a `String.trim()` function, and the above answer will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a reference to `this` in your surrounding `click` handler in order to have access to the element which was clicked inside of the `success` handler:
The `this` inside the `success` handler is **not** the same `this` as your `click` handler.

I like to call it `self` - you can call it whatever you like.

Also, in your `success` handler, you should only perform a subsequent animation once the previous one has finished, so I modified that code to chain the fade sequence one after another.

```
$(".action_button").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var self = this;
  var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
  var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "action.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function()
      {
          if(id % 2)
          {
              parent.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                 $(self).fadeOut('normal', function() { 
                    $(self).fadeIn();
                 }); 
              });
          }
          else
          {
              parent.fadeOut('fast', function() { 
                 $(self).fadeIn('normal', function() { 
                    $(self).fadeOut();
                 }); 
              });
          }
       }
   });
});
```